# DC/OS packages not exist

Tags: docker, mesosphere, dcos

I added two repository in DC/OS repositories.

1. https://github.com/mesosphere/multiverse/archive/version-1.x.zip
2. https://universe.mesosphere.com/repo

But nothing showed in my **Universe Packages** page! and I get the following error:

> undefined You can go to the Repositories Settings page to change installed repositories.

where i can see more related error messages (except in journalctl)

My DCOS version is 1.8.4 and I have also a VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `https://github.com/mesosphere/multiverse/archive/version-1.x.zip` from the repositories.

Comment: I remove it, but give the same error! although I can install from the CLI, but not from GUI.